# Why does one need to specify the row while assigning a pointer to a 2D Array?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, implicit-conversion

The compiler states "assignment from incompatible pointer type" when the row of the 2D array is not mentioned, I always thought an array without brackets means the address of the first element, in this case address of the element twodstring[0][0]

Compiler does not state an error when the row is mentioned, I was wondering why is this the case?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

  char onedstring[]={"1D Array"};
  char twodstring[][5]={"2D","Array"};
  char *p1,*p2;

  p1=onedstring;
  p2=twodstring;
  p2=twodstring[1];

}
```

Comment: `twodstring` is of type `char **`

Comment: Hint: What type is `twodstring`?

Comment: @tadman: I was thinking twodstring is of type char?

Comment: @xhg: Why is twodstring of type char **?

Comment: @xhg - No it is not.

Comment: @AMD @StoryTeller Oh yep I was wrong and it it not `char **` lol. The idea was it is a 2D char array, which cannot be assigned to a 1D pointer.

Comment: @tadman **oh so wrong** .... What you describe would be declared as `char *twodstring[]={"2D","Array"};`.

Comment: @xhg a "1d pointer"? :o

Comment: @FelixPalmen well.. pointer to the first element of the that 1d array.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I was speaking in general terms. This all goes out the window with fixed-size allocations like `x[][5]`.

Answer (score 5):

A two-dimensional array

```
char a[M][N];
```

can be declared using a typedef the following way

```
typedef char T[N];

T a[M];
```

So a pointer to the first element of the array `a` can be declared like

```
T *p = a;
```

where `T` is an alias for the type `char[N]`. Now making the reverse substitution we can write

```
char ( *p )[N] = a;
```

That is elements of a two-dimensional array are one-dimensional arrays.

This declaration

```
char ( *p )[N] = a;
```

is equivalent to

```
char ( *p )[N] = &a[0];
```

where `a[0]` has the type `char[N]`. So the pointer points to the first "row" of the array.

Dereferencing the pointer you will get an object of the type `char[N]`.

Pay attention to that a two-dimensional array can be declared like

```
char ( a[M] )[N];
```

So substituting the one-dimensional array declarator `a[M]` for pointer you will get

```
char ( a[M] )[N];
char (  *p  )[N] = a;
```

If you will declare a pointer like this

```
char *p1;
```

then you may write for example

```
p1 = a[1];
```

in this expression `a[1]` is a one-dimensional array of the type `char[N]`. Using the expression as an initializer the array is converted to pointer to its first element that has the type `char *`.

So this expression statement

```
p1 = a[1];
```

is equivalent to

```
p1 = &a[1][0];
```

Dereferencing this pointer you will get an object of the type `char`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what would be the case if it were to be a 3D array? Would the above answer apply for a 3D array as well?

Comment: @AMD So if you have char a[N]; then the pointer is char *p = a; If you have char a[M][N]; then the pointer is char ( *p )[N] = a; If you have char a[N1][N2][N3]; then the pointer is char ( *p )[N2][N3]; That is the left-most dimension is substituted for the pointer.

Answer (score 4):

Let's look at these lines:

```
char twodstring[][5]={"2D","Array"};
char *p2;
p2=twodstring;
```

In the last line, you just write the identifier of an array. This evaluates to a pointer to the first array element. But this first array element doesn't have the type `char` -- it is an array itself with the type `char [5]`.

If you want this assignment to work, you have to declare `p2` with the correct type like this:

```
char twodstring[][5]={"2D","Array"};
char (*p2)[5];
p2=twodstring;
```

Comment: I may just be late in my time zone, and I should go rest, but what does `char ()` in `char ()[5]` mean?

Comment: A placeholder where the declared identifier would go ... I've seen this often to specify an array type.

Comment: `char ()[5]` is the type of a function with unspecified argument list returning `char[5]`. (Which is a constraint violation, since functions cannot return arrays). You probably meant `char[5]`

Comment: See C11 6.7.7 (footnote 147)

Comment: @M.M yes, it's not *formally* correct (e.g. as operand of `sizeof`), but you still see it used that way for clarity in free-form explanations. I definitely don't mean `char[5]` because this is, although syntactically correct, quite misleading, especially for learners (for the same reason I find `int*` misleading). But alright, I'll change it to `char [5]` -- IMHO not as obvious, but still correct when used in C source.

Comment: I've never seen `char()[5]` written to mean `char[5]` outside of your answer here . Also I would suggest that if someone finds the correct type misleading then a good remedy to that is to learn more about the type system

Comment: @Felix Palmen "But this first array element doesn't have the type char -- it is an array itself with the type char [5]." Can you explain this statement in a bit of detail? I always thought char is the type, and [5] would be a size declaration, I never knew there is type char[5]?

Comment: @AMD not sure how to answer this ... read **§6.5.2 Types** in [the latest C11 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). In a nutshell, `char` is the *basic type*, an array of char is a *derived type*. You can't write `char[5] x;` as a declaration if that's what you mean, and that's the reason I preferred to put a placeholder when talking about it, but indeed, if you need to write **just a type name**, this works by omitting the identifier in the declaration syntax ... the type of `char x[5]` therefore is `char [5]`.