# Can gcc display the pointer types when reporting "assignment from incompatible pointer type"?

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

Earlier today I was looking into this question:  [Why does one need to specify the row while assigning a pointer to a 2D Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47081504/why-does-one-need-to-specify-the-row-while-assigning-a-pointer-to-a-2d-array)  There was some confusion/disagreement regarding the types involved when attempting to assign the identifier of a multi-dimensional array to a pointer.  Specifically, whether it would "decay" or "convert" (or whatever your preferred nomenclature may be, as there seems to be disagreement about that as well) to a `char **` or a `char ()[5]` or a `char (*)[5]`.

(Based on comments below, I'm including the code sample from the linked question here.  Don't blame me, I didn't write it.)

```
int main()
{
  char onedstring[]={"1D Array"};
  char twodstring[][5]={"2D","Array"};
  char *p1,*p2;

  p1=onedstring;
  p2=twodstring;
  p2=twodstring[1];
}
```

I tested how my compiler reports the warning from the code in that question and got this result:
(Compiler: gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4))

```
decay.c:15:7: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     p2=twodstring;
```

It reports incompatible pointer types but does not report the types involved, which would be quite helpful in this instance.  I haven't found a way (yet) to get that particular warning to also display the types.  However, I have found that calling a function instead of assignment *does* result in a note that includes the types.  Here is example code (and please note that it serves absolutely no purpose other than to generate a compiler warning):

```
void function_to_trigger_warning(char *c){}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char onedstring[]={"1D Array"};
    char twodstring[][5]={"2D","Array"};

    function_to_trigger_warning(onedstring);
    function_to_trigger_warning(twodstring);

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the warning output:

```
decay.c: In function ‘main’:
decay.c:20:33: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘function_to_trigger_warning’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     function_to_trigger_warning(twodstring);
                                 ^
decay.c:7:6: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[5]’
 void function_to_trigger_warning(char *c)
      ^
```

Looks like according to gcc the `twodstring` is treated as a `char (*)[5]` for the purposes of pointer assignment.  That is valuable information!

Long story short (I know, too late): **Is there a way in gcc to get similar output from other pointer assignment warnings**?

Comment: With the version of gcc I'm using, apparently not - in a regular assignment between incompatible pointer types, I just get `assignment from incompatible pointer type`.  As for determining what an array expression "decays" to, an array of `T` decays to a pointer to `T` - if `T` is a scalar like `int`, then array of `int` decays to pointer to `int`.  If `T` is "array of `int`", then an array of array of `int` decays to a pointer to an array of `int`, etc.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where the expected information is not shown

Comment: @M.M - As indicated in the post, I used the code sample from the linked question.  I saw no reason to copy that code here.  If others think it is helpful/necessary then I will do so.

Comment: It is obvious. No need IMO. It is easy to check.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 - the reason for inclusion here as opposed to a link is there is no guarantee the link will still work a year from now rendering the question and answers that rely on the linked content worthless. All necessary code should be included in the question.

Comment: @David C. Rankin what link? I do not see any in my comment,

Comment: The comment was a follow on to MM request for MCVE and me misinterpreting your comment. Good general info anyway `:)`

Comment: @AndrewCottrell *"Is there a way in gcc to get similar output from other pointer assignment warnings?"* Yes. gcc does type checking of parameters. `char *` and `char (*)[5]` are two completely different types. Pointer arithmetic works completely differently for each. For `char *`, `p++` advances one character, with `char (*)[5]` it advances 5-characters at a time. Any mismatch in parameter types will prompt the warning. (and "*converted*" is the terminology used in the C standard, "*decay*" is a common reference to the same thing)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - I think you've lost sight of the actual question: 'Can gcc display the pointer types when reporting “assignment from incompatible pointer type”?'

Comment: @M.M - Ok, copied in the example code from the linked question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install a newer version of gcc.  With gcc 8.1 or newer, your example yields the warning:

```
foo1.c: In function ‘main’:
foo1.c:8:5: warning: assignment to ‘char *’ from incompatible pointer type ‘char (*)[5]’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    8 |   p2=twodstring;
      |     ^
```

[Try it on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/DPrTP2).  (If necessary, click the "Output" button at the bottom of the compiler window to see the warning.)

Comment: Nice.  Glad to see they finally updated it.  I'll select your new answer as the correct one.

Comment: @AndrewCottrell: This feature was actually [added to the trunk](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=commit;h=296c53ac8ad2a1ec74) way back in August 2017 - almost three months before your original question :-)

Comment: Ha!  Unfortunately, like a lot of firmware developers, I'm often stuck with whatever compiler the vendor has provided.  It's old and buggy IDEs, compilers, and tools all the way down.

Comment: @AndrewCottrell You may be able to run a side by side build with a newer compiler to get the improved diagnostics , even if you need to use the vendor compiler to generate the binary